# R in Python. Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vector

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I just started trying to use R in Python as there are interesting packages. I am using the package rpy2 to use R in python environment. Could somebody help me to understand why I have this error? I don't use the $ in my code. The error occurred at fitMCMC.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro
ms = importr('MSGARCH')
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri, numpy2ri, vectors
pandas2ri.activate()
numpy2ri.activate()
base = importr('base')
stats = importr('stats')


spec = ms.CreateSpec(variance_spec = ro.ListVector( ro.StrVector(['sGARCH', 'sGARCH'])),
              distribution_spec = ro.ListVector( ro.StrVector(['norm', 'norm']))
              )

X = my_data
fitMCMC = ms.FitMCMC(spec = spec, data = X, ctr = ro.ListVector({'nburn' : '500L', 'nmcmc' : '500L', 'nthin' : '1L'}))
print(base.summary(fitMCMC))
```

Comment: After which line does the error occur? The error is an R error. Usually happens when a function expects a data frame or list, while the input is a vector. If you run `base = importr('base')` at the beginning and `base.traceback()` after the error occurs you will get more info about where the error happend, but will probably be very messy

Comment: adibender thank you fir your answer. The error occurred at fitMCMC

Comment: would also add that the function FitMCMC is expecting a vector as data. See this source https://rdrr.io/cran/MSGARCH/man/FitMCMC.html

Comment: Why are you bracketing, `[]` the items in `ListVector` of *ctr* argument, translating Python lists? You might be passing a nested list object. Btw - `summary` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: yes, the documentation says vector, but when you run the examples, the `SMI` object is actually of class `zoo` which is specific object to handle time-series that might have different behaviour compared to "normal" vectors.

Comment: adibender thank you. your hint helped me. my data was actually a pd.dataframe. i managed to remove the error by changing it to np.array before to put it in the fitMCMC function. I still have another error with the ctr parameters. But it is not the basic purpose of the request.

Comment: @maf could you post your solution as an answer?